# Find $a_i, b_i$ such that they are all distinct

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Very tough, I spent at least an hour, not solving this!

> From the set of integers $ \{1,2,3,\ldots,2009\}$, choose $ k$ pairs $ \{a_i,b_i\}$ with $ a_i<b_i$ so that no two pairs have a common element. Suppose that all the sums $ a_i+b_i$ are distinct and less than or equal to $ 2009$. Find the maximum possible value of $ k$.

So each element can only be used once.

$k_1 = \{1, 2 \}$ and $k_2 = \{3, 4  \}$

The maximum difference possible set is $A = \{1, 2008 \}$. $2008$ can be used once, $2007$ once [ 1, 2007], $2006$ once [1, 2006].

But it gets very confusing?

**HINTS please?**

Comment: Hint:  it is fairly easy to get a good upper bound on $k$.  Take your maximal list and add all the terms.  As the elements are all distinct you get a lower bound on the sum (involving $k$).  As the sums are distinct and bounded by $2009$ you get an upper bound on the sum (also involving $k$).  As the lower bound can not exceed the upper bound, we get an inequality which ends up giving you an upper bound on $k$.

Comment: I am able to get $669 \le k \le 803$. But I have no idea about the sharpness of the upper bound or how to find a better pairing for the lower bound.

Comment: I got $k \le 1004$. @lulu,

Comment: Not sure where $1004$ comes from, I got $803$ as did $yultan .  Of course, this does not solve the problem. But, to me, it seems like the upper bound is the hardest part.  It is (relatively) easy to find large collections...much harder to show that they are maximal (or so it seems to me).

Comment: More precise hint:  having first established $803$ as a theoretical upper bound, try to find a collection of $803$ pairs that works.

Comment: @lulu, but how to establish that first?

Comment: I'll write that up and post it below.  I don't want to solve the problem fully, however...you were just after hints, no?

Comment: @lulu, I am always after hints, if you can give me a hint on establishing the upper bound then that is even better!

Comment: My first comment on the inequality was a hint!  I have written it out below...but before looking at that, go back to what I wrote and write out everything carefully.  It's not that bad a calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already gave hints yourself :-)

2009 cannot be in a pair, because already {2009, 1} leads to a sum that is larger than 2009. The remaining 2008 elements of the set can be in a pair.

Each element can only be used once. Since there are two elements in each pair, the number of pairs cannot be larger than the number of usable elements in the set divided by two:

$k \leq \frac{2008}{2}$.

How many unique pairs can you form if you go $k_1=\{1,2008\}, k_2=\{2,2007\}, \dots$?

Comment: I think $1004$ but those are invalid since $2008 + 1 = 2 + 2007$

Comment: You are right. I'm sorry, I missed the "sums are distinct" part.

Answer (score 2):

PARTIAL SOLUTION (UPPER BOUND)

As sketched out in some of the comments, a critical step in the problem is establishing a good upper bound.  It isn't terribly hard to come up with good candidates...hard to see how to show that one of them is actually maximal.

So.  Take a maximal list, say it has $k$ elements.  Sum up all the elements that appear in your list, let $\mathscr S$ denote that sum.  As all the elements are distinct, we must have $$\mathscr S\;≥\;1+2+3\;+\;...+\;2k\;=\;k(2k+1)$$

Now, recompute the sum by adding them up pair by pair.  As all the pair sums are distinct and bounded above by $2009$ we must have:

$$\mathscr S \;≤\;2009+2008\;+\;...\;+\;2009-(k-1)\;=\;2009k-\frac {k(k-1)}{2}\;=\;\frac {k(4019-k)}{2}$$

Combining these two inequalities we see that $$\frac {k(4019-k)}{2}≥k(2k+1)$$

Divide by $k$ and rearrange terms to get $$4017≥5k$$ from which we see at once that $$k≤803$$

(Note:  we used the fact that $k$ must be an integer).

Now all you need to do is to construct a list with $803$ elements.  Note:  this is not as hard as it sounds.  Hint:  try to use as many small integers as you possibly can.

Comment: How is it upto $2k$? (+1)

Comment: You have $k$ pairs, hence $2k$ elements.  They all have to be distinct, so the smallest they could be is $1, 2, 3, ..., 2k$.

Answer (score 0):

We let $k_i=\{i,1205+i\}$ for $i$ from 1 to 401 and $k_i=\{i,402+i\}$ for {i} from 402 to 803.

For $i$ between 1 and 401, the $a_i$ and $b_i$ range from 1-401 and 1206-1606 respectively. For $i$ between 402 and 803, the $a_i$ and $b_i$ range from 402-803 and  804-1205 respectively. The maximum sum for $1\le i\le401$ is $401+1606=2007$, and all sums are odd. The maximum sum for $402\le i\le803$ is $803+1205=2008$ and all sums are even.